# Postgresql ERROR: could not load library plpgsql.so undefined symbol

Tags: postgresql

My Postgresql installation is working, but when I call a particular function I get an undefined symbol `HeapTupleHeaderGetDatum`, and `plpgsql.so` will not load.

*This is going to be a Question and Answer, the reason for this Q&A is that the current answers here don't turn up in google search results and I hope this will help others*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Restart the Postgresql database,

You've changed versions of postgresql and forgotten to restart.

This can be checked by running `postgres --version` from the host

```
$ postgres --version 
postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.1.15
```

Vs. `select version();` from the psql prompt:

```
pg=# select version();

                         version
PostgreSQL 9.1.12 on x86_64-suse-linux-gnu, compiled by ....
```

Answer (score 1):

A more likely cause of this for many people will be that the `libpq` found by the dynamic linker is older than the one a client program like `psql` was compiled against. `ldd psql` (or whatever the problem client is) will usually help indicate if this is the case.

BTW, it's not a great idea to hot-replace the binaries. Better to stop the server, replace the binaries, and start the server. This is true of most things on Linux. You *can* replace the binaries, but unless they're utterly 100% binary compatible *kaboom* may result. Even then it's only safe-ish if you `unlink()` (e.g. `rm`) the old binaries, *then* create the new ones. If you overwrite in-place you'll modify the memory-mapped binary backing  running code, which will have exciting and colourful results.

Comment: Good point about the hot-replace, I forgot it was still running when trying to sort out some PostGIS dependency issues.